# Finding the size of the longest sequence of consecutive numbers in a random array of size 1xn using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sequence

I would like to find the size of the longest sequence of consecutive numbers in a random array of size 1xn using Matlab. I know that there are two ways to do this: 1) using a loop and 2) using Matlab functions e.g. find, but I am unsure about how to do this without using both?

E.G. `[1 2 3 5 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 17]`

The longest sequence in this would be 10 11 12 13 14, which would be of size 5.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
function [start, finish] = longest(sequence)

x = diff(t)==1;

f = find([false,x]~=[x,false]);

g = find(f(2:2:end)-f(1:2:end-1)>=N,1,'first');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variables don't match, but assuming that `all(t == sequence)` you are on the right track. You want to distinguish between the start of each run and the end by doing a second `diff`.

```
% Mark all sequences
x = diff(sequence) == 1;

% Take the second derivative to find the edges
xx = diff([false, x, false]);

% This gives matched pairs of indexes for each block
initial = find(xx == 1);
final = find(xx == -1);

% Get the block length
blockLength = final - initial;

% Get the max length
[~, idx] = max(blockLength);

% Return the indices
start = initial(idx);
finish = final(idx);
```

The result on your test gives `start = 5`, `finish = 11`. If you want to also return the block length, replace the `~` with your variable name

Comment: That's a great help, managed to sort it out thanks. My friend mentioned it would be possible to do it with just loops (i.e.) without the diff and max built in function but I don't know where to start with this? I'm guessing something along the lines of writing a loop to keep counting and saving the length of each sequence, then replacing that length if it finds a longer one. How would you write this?

Comment: Given that MATLAB is generally optimized for vectorization, the answer is that I wouldn't. I see no reason to go through the vector one element at a time when you can let MATLAB do it all in one fell swoop.